# TYPO3: Where can I find the template created in the backend?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to create separate templates for webpages with either a single or a double column structure. Currently my webpage only has one template, placed on the root page which is used by all its subpages.

However, I cannot find the template in myextension/Resources/Private/Templates as this folder is empty. Where is the template located in my extension and where should I add the alternative template?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use "fluid_styled_template"? Then the templates are in that respective core directory, in "Resources/Private".

If you want to manipulate them, copy them to your sitePackage into "Resources/Private/Extension/fluid_styled_content" (that at least is one of the recommended ways where to place it) and override the TypoScript that "fluid_stlyed_content" provides.

Comment: I do not have a folder named Extension in Resources/Private (I only have Language, Layours, Partials and Templates). I'm also not unsure how to find the fluid_style_template core directory (I only see the bootstrap_package and my site package as extensions)

Comment: First, go to the folder "typo3" and there to "sys_ext". In there you find all the system extensions that make up the CMS, also fluid_styled_content.

Then you need to copy the template files (Layouts, Partials, Templates)  of fluid_styled_content and put them at a special place in your extension. One way is to create an "Extensions" folder in your extension's "Resources/Private", where you then create again folders for all the extensions that you override, here: fluid_styled_content. And there you paste the template folders.

Answer (score 0):

`template`is not unique in TYPO3 context. we have:

- typoscript records, maybe also as files which are included in a record or by PHP
- HTML files, which are define a markup for parts of the website
  they can be differed in

  - Marker-Templated. The old and less and less used kind with markers and subparts as placeholders for data defined in typoscript
  - Fluid templates. The modern kind with control structures and data objects

---

with the statemant

> my webpage only has one template, placed on the root page

it is not clear what you mean:

- records are defined in pages -> typoscript templates
- maybe you mean `in the root page a template is selected`. that could mean HTML templates, probably fluid templates as the path `myextension/Resources/Private/Templates` matches the usual structure for fluid templates.

---

assuming **fluid templates**:

Templates are search in a list of folders. This list is managed in typoscript.
Any usage has it's own list  and the list of your main/page template probably is at `page.10.templatePaths`. You can look for it in the TSOB (Typoscript Object browser)

If the list consists of one entry only you have only the basic config.
As the list of folders is consulted each time a template (,partial, layout) is accessed and only that file with matching name in the folder with highest priority is taken you can add your folders with higher numbers in the list so you do not need to change the original files (use copies in your folder to modify) or add files to the original folder (inside of other extensions).

So you need two things:

- create your template file in an appropriate folder
  (`ext:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates` sounds good)
- and add this folder to the list of folders for these templates
  (e.g. `page.10.templatePaths.20 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates`)

Comment: Thank you! how do I use the Typoscript Object browser? Is that somewhere in the backend? I also noticed that I already set EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/ as the templateRootPaths, where else do I need to configure page.10.templatePaths.20 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates?

Comment: originally typoscript was stored only in `sys_template`-records. then you could use includes of files in form of `static template`-files of extensions and with the include statement any file (from fileadmin/ or an extensions). The TSOB can show you the active typoscript of any page and depending on typoscript conditions. if you want to use the TSOB to change the active typoscript you need an active `sys_template`-record in the current page. Changes are added at the end of the field labeled `setup`, named `config`